# Can't Reboot from pishutdown GUI after renaming pi user

Tags: reboot

I didn't check for shutdown, only reboot, because the pi is remote ATM and no easy way to wake it up back.

I renamed the pi user, everything seems OK but this.
Here're info I gathered after reading a similar post about add new user+delete pi user:

```
me@mypi:~ $ groups
me adm dialout cdrom sudo audio video plugdev games users input netdev gpio i2c spi

me@mypi:~ $ id
uid=1000(me) gid=1000(me) groupes=1000(me),4(adm),20(dialout),24(cdrom),27(sudo),29(audio),44(video),
    46(plugdev),60(games),100(users),105(input),109(netdev),997(gpio),998(i2c),999(spi)

me@mypi:~ $ sudo cat /etc/sudoers.d/010_me 
me ALL=(ALL) PASSWD: ALL
```

Many thaks for help

Answer (score 1):

Renaming a user (particularly the admin user) on Linux is a really bad idea.

As you didn't explain what you actually did it is not possible to be more precise.

If you REALLY want to do this you should make a new admin account, and only change/delete users from this.

Even then renaming is not a straightforward process.

Comment: I'm not sure it's a problem with rename the builtin admin (pi) user (even I had to edit /etc/polkit-1/localauthority.conf.d/60-desktop-policy.conf to change hardcoded "pi" to "me"). Instead it seems related to that I use VNC (vncauth) to show the desktop and click the Shutdown/Reboot button from there with no success. But when I run from a terminal the underlying command "lxde-pi-shutdown-helper" I get the following: "User root is logged in on pts/1.Please retry operation after closing inhibitors and logging out other users. Alternatively,ignore inhibitors and users with 'systemctl reboot -i'"